# One Table. Each row has dat for a complete plot

Tags: r, plot, apply, gridextra

Can I use apply() with plot() in the argument to plot each row? If not then in gridextra, (multiplot) how do I use the same problem, i.e. a single table row containing title and data of a graph series

The data is

```
A 1 2 3 4 5
B 1 0 2 0 4
C 2 0 4 0 7
```

etc. 
And I want a multiplot to compare A, B and C.

Comment: Please correct the spelling. R is case sensitive. And wouldn't this just be `apply(dat[-1], 1, plot)` perhaps with `layout` to put them on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the `matplot` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the use of `ggplot`, here's a way to do it nicely. Let's say that your data is a data frame named `data`. Then

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
data.melt <- melt(cbind(data, index=1:nrow(data)), id.vars="index")
ggplot(data.melt, aes(y=value, x=index, factor=variable, col=variable)) + geom_point()
```